# How can a `Shell Text` be converted to `Shell Line`?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

In a Turtle script for getting passwords from a keyring, calling `ssh-add` with those passwords so they don't have to be filled out manually, is the following function:

```
processKey :: (T.Text, T.Text) -> Shell Line -> IO ()
processKey (kn, str) pwds = do
    -- Not sure why (text str) is needed here, but it won't typecheck without
    -- it (despite OverloadedStrings).
    let expectArg = do
        ml <- grep (contains (text str)) pwds
        let pass = getPwd $ cut tab (format l ml)
        return $ T.unlines [ "<< EOF"
                  , "spawn ssh-add"
                  , "expect \"Enter passphrase\""
                  , "send " <> pass
                  , "expect eof"
                  , "EOF"
                  ]
    view (inproc "expect" [] expectArg)
    where
       -- Safely get the third item `cut` from the list.
       getPwd xs = getPwd' 0 xs
       getPwd' _ []     = ""
       getPwd' n (x:xs) = if n == 2
                          then x
                          else getPwd' (n+1) xs
```

This function takes a tuple of (SSH key file name, string to search for in the text stored in the keyring), and `pwds :: Shell Line` that is the entire contents of the keyring taken from a shell command.

The purpose of the function is to `grep` the passwords, and call `ssh-add` with the key filename and password.

The problem is this function doesn't type check:

```
sshkeys-autopass.hs:45:30: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Line’
      Expected type: Shell Line
        Actual type: Shell Text
    • In the third argument of ‘inproc’, namely ‘expectArg’
      In the first argument of ‘view’, namely
        ‘(inproc "expect" [] expectArg)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: view (inproc "expect" [] expectArg)
   |
45 |     view (inproc "expect" [] expectArg)
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems like `Shell Line` needs to become `Shell Text`, how can this be done, please? I am open to the possibility this is structured badly or is not idiomatic Haskell (it does smell), if so please advise how this function could be better.

Comment: You could do `(lineToText <$> expectArg)` probably. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.2/docs/Turtle-Line.html#v:lineToText

Comment: @dimsuz Thanks, I didn't see that documentation for `Line` before. The type checker is looking for `Shell Line` and not `Shell Text` though. There are functions that almost do what's required, but the argument for `expect` contains newlines and `textToLine` is Nothing if the text contains newlines.

Comment: A `Line` is a `Text` which is guaranteed to have no newlines. If you have `x :: Text` and `x` contains newlines then there is no value of type `Line` which represents the same string as `x`, by definition. You must split your text into a list of lines, using [`textToLines`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.2/docs/Turtle-Line.html#v:textToLines)

Comment: @user2407038 Indeed! But that causes another problem: `inproc` does not want a `Shell (NonEmpty Line)`. I have no idea what to do about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I can't try out your code right now, it seems roundtripping your commands through `Text` (as `T.unlines` forces you to) is causing unnecessary trouble. According [to the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.2/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#t:Shell) (emphasis mine):

> A `(Shell a)` is a protected *stream* of `a`'s with side effects

As a `Shell Line` is a stream, it can supply multiple `Line`s. And sure enough, there is a function called [`select`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.2/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#v:select)...

> `select :: Foldable f => f a -> Shell a`

... which will convert a list (or any other `Foldable`) to a `Shell`. You can use it to get the `Shell Line` you need directly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
-- etc.
    let expectArg = do
        ml <- grep (contains (text str)) pwds
        -- unsafeTextToLine is presumably safe here,
        -- as ml was a Line to begin with.
        let pass = unsafeTextToLine . getPwd $ cut tab (format l ml)
        select [ "<< EOF"
            , "spawn ssh-add"
            , "expect \"Enter passphrase\""
            , "send " <> pass
            , "expect eof"
            , "EOF"
            ]
    view (inproc "expect" [] expectArg)
```

---

Side questions:

> Not sure why `(text str)` is needed here, but it won't typecheck without it (despite OverloadedStrings).

The only thing `OverloadedStrings` does automatically is handling string literals. It won't silently convert `Text` values to other instances of `IsString`. An alternative to using `text` would be changing your signature so that the type of `str` is `Pattern Text` rather than `Text`.

> Safely get the third item `cut` from the list.

Here is one way of writing `getPwd` without writing the recursive algorithm explicitly, using a few functions from [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html):

```
getPwd = fromMaybe "" . listToMaybe . drop 2
```

You might also like the [`atDef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.16/docs/Safe.html#v:atNote) from the *safe* package:

```
getPwd xs = atDef "" xs 2
```

> But that causes another problem: `inproc` does not want a `Shell (NonEmpty Line)`. I have no idea what to do about this.

[`NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) is a type for lists that are guaranteed to have at least one element. In your case, the lack of a sensible way of going from `NonEmpty Line` to `Line` (concatenating the elements or picking the first one, for instance, wouldn't help at all) was a signal that a change of approach was necessary.

Comment: This is a great answer, I'll check whether it works in a bit and (assuming it does) mark it accepted. Thank you so much for all the extra detail, I really appreciate it.
'...the lack of a sensible way of going from NonEmpty Line to Line (concatenating the elements or picking the first one, for instance, wouldn't help at all) was a signal that a change of approach was necessary.'  Yes, exactly! I could tell there was something fundamentally wrong with my approach, but didn't know where to go next.

Comment: Everything in this answer works, including replacing the recursive algorithm with functions from `Data.Maybe` and using `Pattern Text` instead of just `Text` (I like this solution in particular). Thank you.